# Validate a US phone number from an optional input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [**jQuery Validation Plugin**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a phone number from an optional input field.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="input-form" action="" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name <span>(required, at least 3 characters)</span></label>
      <input id="name" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">E-Mail <span>(required)</span></label>
      <input id="email" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="phone">Phone <span>(optional, US phone number only)</span></label>
      <input id="phone" name="phone">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </p>
</form>
```

Here is what I have tried to set the rules to validate the input field for phone number

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input-form").validate({
    rules: {
      name : {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: {
          depends: function(elem) {
            return $("#phone").val().length == 11
          }
        }
      }
    },
    messages : {
      name: {
        minlength: "Name should be at least 3 characters"
      },
      email: {
        email: "The email should be in the format: abc@domain.tld"
      },
      phone: {
        required: "Please enter a valid US phone number"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It's still not working. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to validate the input field for phone number.
Here is my solution:

```
rules: {
   phone: {
      required: {
         depends: function(elem) {
            return $("#phone").val().length > 9
         }
      },
      number: true,
      rangelength: [10, 10]
   }
},
messages: {
   phone: {
       required: "Please enter a valid US phone number",
       number: "Please enter only numbers for phone number",
       rangelength: "Please enter a valid US phone number"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the additional-methods.js file are several phone number validation methods you can use **phoneUS** should satisfy your pattern

```
rules: {
    phoneNumber: {
        phoneUS: true
    }
}
```

Comment: ```phoneUS: true``` only works if the phone input is set as required. My phone input is set as optional. It only validates the input when users enter something on the input field.